# using NSWorkspace activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:atFilesDest without activating finder

Tags: objective-c, selection, finder, nsworkspace

I´m using this to select a bunch of files in the frontmost finder window which works fine:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:atFilesDest];
```

However, the finder comes to front what I actually don't want.

Any clues how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but for the sake of any other googlers out there like me, I would suggest using an AppleScript or using [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) (probably Scripting Bridge).

Then, you could do a "select" command in the Finder and just not do an "activate" command so the Finder wouldn't be activated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was using Terminal to workaround an Xcode bug where my suite of Apps sometimes get stuck in the Dock.
(I'm still trying to solve why Xcode has this bug.)

This workaround caused activateFileViewerSelectingURLs a.k.a. 'Reveal In Finder...' to stop working:

```
sudo killall launchservicesd; sudo killall Dock;
```

And this new workaround fixes the 'Reveal In Finder' problem:

```
sudo killall launchservicesd; sudo killall Dock; sudo killall Finder;
```

ORIGINAL PROBLEM:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:urls];
```

Finder is no longer brought to the front, and my apps' window typically obscures the Finder window, so the user has no idea what just happened.

I can't find a workaround that activates Finder and brings it to the front.

I have tried various things like [NSApp deactivate] and other NSApp api's.  Anyone else having this problem?  I noticed El Cap changes the way spotlight works to hide 'Reveal In Finder...' way down at the bottom of the list.